# Edgeを垂直タブで起動するコマンド

Tags: windows, command-line

Edgeのコマンド引数(msedge ~~)で垂直タブで起動したいのですがコマンドは存在しますでしょうか？
以下のサイトを拝見しましたが古い(？)ためか記載されていませんでした。
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/get-list-of-edge-command-line-switches/519d9efd-03df-4815-9cc7-b8f51d1bc932

もしくは、Edgeのコマンド引数を確認する方法でも構いません。
上記サイトでOrcaを利用して確認するとの記載がありましたが、
理解できずご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: GUIの手作業で行う解説記事が幾つかありますね。[How to Turn On or Off Vertical Tabs...](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/164365-how-turn-off-vertical-tabs-microsoft-edge-chromium.html), [How to Enable vertical tabs...](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-enable-vertical-tabs-in-edge-browser-of-mircrosoft.html), [How to Use Vertical Tabs...](https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/03/06/use-vertical-tabs-in-microsoft-edge-browser/#dont_see_the_option_enable_vertical_tabs_manually) ちなみに`Orca`(Orceではなく)というのはこちらだと思われます。[Orca.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ご認識の通りOrcaですね。msiのデータベースを編集してどのように出せるようにしたら良いのかわからなかった次第です。また、GUIでの実施方法はご認識のとおりあるのですが、社内システムで垂直タブを強制させたく質問させていただきました。

Comment: 一応垂直タブのOn/Offはブラウザの終了/再起動でも保たれているようなので、何処かにデータは有ると思われますが、公開された情報には無さそうです。マイクロソフトのフォーラム等で聞いてみるのがよいかもしれません。また公開された情報では垂直タブを許さない設定はありますが、垂直タブだけにする設定は無いので、強制は難しいのでは？ キーボードショートカットでOn/Off出来るようですし。